# Implementing IDisposable for WCF service client - Am I doing this right?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I want to safely dispose my WCF client, but I'm not sure if I am implementing IDisposable in the right spot.

I added code to implement IDisposable in the service client inside the Reference.vb file that was created when I added the WCF service as a service reference:

```
Partial Public Class Service1Client
Inherits System.ServiceModel.ClientBase(Of DataConversionService.IService1)
Implements DataConversionService.IService1, IDisposable

Public Sub New()
  MyBase.New
End Sub

'skipping constructors with multiple parameters...

 Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
  Try
    If State <> CommunicationState.Faulted Then
      Close()
    End If
  Finally
    If State <> CommunicationState.Closed Then
      Abort()
    End If
  End Try
End Sub
```

Did I add this in the right spot? When debugging, I wasn't able to hit my breakpoint in the Dispose sub.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Firstly, you shouldn't change that `Reference.vb` file since it will be overwritten when the service definition gets updated and changing that file is not a good practice.

What you can do instead is using [Proxy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). The Proxy will be used to call the methods in services and manage the connection state etc. I will write in C# since I don't know VB but you'll get the idea. I will simplify this as much as I can.

The interface of Proxy class might look like this:

```
public interface IProxy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute call to service method
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TBusiness">Service interface</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">Service method return type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="call">Service method</param>
    /// <returns>Returns what service method returns</returns>
    TResult Execute<TBusiness, TResult>(Func<TBusiness, TResult> call) where TBusiness : class;

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute call to void service method
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TBusiness">Service Interface</typeparam>
    /// <param name="call">Service method</param>
    void Execute<TBusiness>(Action<TBusiness> call) where TBusiness : class;
}
```

As you see, there are two methods in this interface. One of them will be used to call a service method which has a return type, the other one will be used for void methods in the service. You can put non-generic version of these methods to the interface too.

The implementation might be like this:

```
public class ServiceProxy : IProxy
{
    protected void ExecuteCall<TContract>(Action<TContract> code) where TContract : class
    {
        var contractChannel = default(TContract);
        try
        {
            //Create an instance of service client and call the method
            contractChannel = Activator.CreateInstance<TContract>();
            code(contractChannel);
            ((ICommunicationObject)contractChannel).Close();
        }
        catch (FaultException)
        {
            ((ICommunicationObject)contractChannel).Abort();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            ((ICommunicationObject)contractChannel).Abort();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            ((ICommunicationObject)contractChannel).Abort();
        }
    }

    public TResult Execute<TContract, TResult>(Func<TContract, TResult> call) where TContract : class
    {
        return ExecuteCall(call);
    }

    public void Execute<TContract>(Action<TContract> call) where TContract : class
    {
        ExecuteCall(call);
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
var proxy = new ServiceProxy();
proxy.Execute<Service1Client>(a => a.MethodInTheService());
```

What's great about this approach and how you can make it perfect is:

- You might not want to create the proxy as `new ServiceProxy()` but [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) `IProxy` as `ServiceProxy` and use it as WCF client for now but if it changes to Web API in the future e.g., implement and inject `WebApiProxy` then.
- You can use contract interfaces to call the proxy methods.
- You can do whatever you want in the proxy class like caching the channels, getting the service endpoints from the database etc.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, I'm going to need some time to play w the implementation though. C# is close enough!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dispose the client.  In fact, if you dig deep into the code of [ClientBase](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.ServiceModel/R/b6f9da84473940d1.html) you'll see how it already implements IDisposable and when it gets disposed it just calls Close() - which has error handling paths to abort if something goes wrong.

Having said this, I would use a pattern similar to the below to close your client channel (you may need to cast to IChannel on Close and Abort):

```
try
{
    client.Close();
}
catch
{
    client.Abort();
}
```